# How can I conditionally change the nautilus background color?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, colors, git

I would like to have the nautilus background color different if the current folder is being managed by git (i.e., if there is a .git directory in it).  Any ideas how to do that?  Ideal solution would work for all nautilus views (list view & compact view, not just icon view).  I've looked at "gnome color chooser" and at the "window rules" module of ccsm, to no avail.  I'm running 10.04, gnome2, ccsm.

Comment: In the absence of an answer that does what I'm asking, I would also accept an answer saying "here's how to do it in [unity, mint/cinnamon,etc]."

Answer (score 1):

*Note: These steps won't work for GTK-2.0, which I think Ubuntu 10.04 uses.*

Here is how to change the background color of nautilus *in general* (for GTK-3.0):

1. Find the location of your theme. For me it was `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance`
2. It is better to copy this folder in `~/.themes` and then make changes to it, rather than making changes in the original location.
3. Look for `gtk-3.0/apps/nautilus.css` in the `Ambiance` folder.
4. Add these lines at the top of the file:

   `NautilusWindow * {background-color: gray;}`
5. Restart nautilus, using `nautilus -q` command to quit nautilus.
6. You will notice that the background color of browser area changes to gray.

Coming back to your original question, I don't think it's possible to theme nautilus based on location because, changing theme requires nautilus to be restarted. *(If you are OK with restarting of nautilus, I guess then someone can write a script which can play with css, based on current browser location. But again, I'm not too sure of that.)*

Comment: +1: useful information, but not a solution unfortunately.